# windows batch file quits after this line

Tags: batch-file, window

On windows 10, my batch file always quit after this line without any infomation:

```
cd ..\DOC\API && make html & cd ..\..\BUILDALL
```

I stared at this line for long and cannot figure out why lines after this one cannot execute. I also tried the following line and its shows the correct directory.

```
cd ..\DOC\API && make html & cd ..\..\BUILDALL & dir
```

Comment: The `Make` command will only be run if the directory successfully changes to the adjacent `DOC\API` directory, _(relative to your current directory)_. The `BUILDALL` directory, which is also adjacent to the original current directory, will only become current upon completion of the `Make` command. The directory listing will be invoked within `API` or `BUILDALL`. My assumption if you have no directory listing is that `make html` hasn't completed, or `DOC\API` was not adjacent to the current directory at the time it was invoked. It should be simple enough to see which of those scenarios is true.

Comment: If the `BUILDALL` directory listing shows, and your batch file quits, then your script parser has read an end of file command or marker. If the `API` directory is listed, then your `BUILDALL` directory was not found along side your original current directory. What directory listing do you get? and what is the line which follows that one?

Comment: Windows 10 does not have a native `MAKE` command.

Comment: That `make` - is it `make.bat`? Then you need to `call` it to be able to return to your original script.

Comment: The last ‘dir’ showed correct directory, but the batch file terminated there.

Comment: Yes, it does. Because you did all on one line, which is parsed as a whole (before the parser doesn't return from `make.bat`).  (Hey, it's a batch file - why pressing several commands into one line in the first place instead of keeping it readable and maintainable and easy to troubleshoot?)

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, I didn't realize that it is a make.bat. Adding call solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Stephen pointed out, 'make' is a batch file, and a windows batch file terminate when execute another batch file, unless we call that batch file.  So this is correct:

```
cd ..\DOC\API && call make html & cd ..\..\BUILDALL
```

Like others did, I checked the directories again and again, and even used the following line to check it:

```
cd ..\DOC\API && make html & cd ..\..\BUILDALL & dir
```

Even the last `dir` outputs correctly, the batch file still terminate for the reason explained above. `dir` could show correctly since the line is parsed altogether.

soembadhat explained from a different perspective.